# Permission denied adding a member to a group in Google Cloud Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm new to GCP. I setup my organisation yesterday which involved creating a new Google Identity (or perhaps turning it on, or both, it's not clear whether it's an entity or a service) and linking it to my app's domain.

There was also a step-by-step wizard to get started with some things, including making a bunch of groups and assigning them roles.

I'm trying to add my personal Google account as a member of one of the groups. I have added my other self as a "principal" in IAM.

But when I try to add that principal as a member, I get this error.

Failed to add members
The following members failed to be added to the group group-name@app.domain

- xxx@gmail.com (permission denied)

I've left it 24h, which has worked for another odd problem I had, but not this. What's really worrying me is that I have no other account. I'm using the new account I was coerced into setting up, so I would rather hope it was God-like.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect (don't know) that the Group that you created is (by default) restricted to email addresses from the custom domain that you're using (for the Org and for Groups). This smells like a good default setting (don't let users inadvertently add random non-org people to the Group). I recommend reviewing the Group settings to see whether such a restriction exists.

Comment: Organizations were added to GCP more recently than some of the platform's other (security) resource types. Folders similarly. Projects were the original security perimeter. Similarly, GCP reasonably absorbed Google's broader identity, groups etc. types as these (like Microsoft accounts) are used across the platform. You may see some 'curiosities' (rough edges) as a result but, the upside is, that this arrangement is consistent and proven. Hopefully this helps you navigate it. The docs are good.

Comment: Thanks so much Daz. I've just added the "basic" Owner permission to my new domain-link identity principal and my personal principal but I still get "permission denied", so maybe you're right about @gmail.com being rejected and a bad UX around this. I've emailed Thomas Kurian because I've really had nothing but problems. It's odd because, as you say, the docs, as well as other great Google UX like Google Domains, are what have drawn me to GCP from Azure. I wish the same UX team were assigned to GCP.

Comment: I'm less familiar with Google Identity (Platform) as I'm "old school" and only ever used the old (Google Apps) approach. I'll have a quick google. I was once at Microsoft and more recently at Google (in Cloud Platform) and so, while I'm very familiar with GCP, I like to think I can be objective about it too. It's an excellent platform and the UI is generally decent but, these "rough edges" (which most evolved platforms incur) are always tough.

Comment: I suspect (don't know) this: https://support.google.com/a/answer/167097#external&zippy=%2Ccan-external-users-participate-in-groups Are you able to browse the Groups that you created using `groups.google.com`? The URL should present your current Google account's (corporate) list of groups.

Comment: Cool, thanks, I'll plough through that documentation later and I'll look into org policies that I can toggle. I can see my groups via that link, I've never seen this before, there're all sorts of settings in here, so I'll take a good look after I've had a beer in the bath :)

Comment: Hi Luke, do you have the link to the wizard you used to configure your environment?
I would like to reproduce the environment and check if I get the same behavior.

Comment: @VicenteAyala Hi, yup. So I don't recall how I *began* the whole journal from logged-in with my personal account to setting up Google Identity, some of that was in another wizard it felt like, but the one that led me almost to creating (unnecessary) VPC projects is under Identity & Organisation and then "Go to the checklist". Expect to see 10 steps on the left and it's to set up a Google Cloud "foundation".

Comment: @VicenteAyala Since I've gone back in there, I notice that I somehow didn't mark step 1 as complete, so it's taken me back there. I've marked it complete, and now I can see the point at which I bailed out. I think I became suspicious that I didn't want any of this, since it's just me in my organisation. I then looked ahead at the Networking and got really put off by it all and never came back. I wonder if this wizard is mandatory, or has parts that are mandatory to complete once started. Let me complete (5) and see what happens.

Comment: Okay, now I remember! On step 5, under "Create initial projects..." I saw the VPC projects and bailed out. I must have abandoned some of the things to do in step 6, like add roles to those groups.

Comment: Yes, and also it has a group for DevOps which I don't agree with. DevOps is a movement about developers are also ops, there's no silo, and this wizard wants me to setup a silo. In addition to it being overkill for a solopreneur!

Comment: @VicenteAyala So I completed adding the roles to the other groups but I still have (permission denied) when trying to add my Gmail account to the developers group. I'll carry on reading and looking into DazWilkin suggestions.

Comment: @LukePuplett well you have made a little progress checking the steps you missed at the beginning. According to the documentation it might take up to 24 hours to reflect the changes made, I don't know if applicable for every change done.
Service availability
It can take up to 24 hours for Google services to be available to the new user. If the user attempts to use a service that's not yet available, they'll see a message that they don't have access to it.

Comment: @DazWilkin Hey, do you want to post a proper answer? The solution was indeed to allow external members by finding and ticking the organisational setting on admin.google.com titled "Group owners can allow external members". You said it would be this, and you pointed at the correct docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For posterity:

When created, (Google) Groups default to internal members only, i.e. those users with accounts on the domain used by Group. This is a good "secure by default" practice as it prohibits inadvertently adding non-organization members to Groups.

However, admins who wish to permit external (e.g. @gmail.com) users can "allow external members" using [Google Admin](https://admin.google.com).

See: [Can external users participate in Google Groups](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167097#external&zippy=%2Ccan-external-users-participate-in-groups)